# I have multiple text boxes (tbVarName1, tbVarName2, ... tbVarName[n]) and I want to increment them in a for loop to assign the text to something

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop, textbox

I have a multiple text boxes that I want to assign their string content to a variable however I'm not sure how to increment the text boxes. They are named, tbVarName1, tbVarname2, et cetera. Below is the for loop I have, right now I just have tbVarName1 hard coded in.

I have researched some of what other people have done and have only found tips for doing it in VB.

```
        for(seriesIndex = 1; seriesIndex <= 4; seriesIndex++)
        {
                dataChart.Series["Variable " + seriesIndex].LegendText = tbVarName1.Text 
        }
```

At the end of this I would like the the legends to be updated to what's in the text boxes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, one way is to add the controls into an array, for example:

```
var controls = new [] { tbVarName1, tbVarName2, tbVarName3 };
```

And now you can access them by index:

```
for(seriesIndex = 1; seriesIndex <= 4; seriesIndex++)
{
    dataChart.Series["Variable " + seriesIndex].LegendText = controls[seriesIndex - 1].Text;
    //                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                                                       Like this
    //                                                       Note: arrays start at zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is using the Controls collection from the Form (assuming that all TextBoxes are direct children of the form)

```
var ctrl = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
for(seriesIndex = 1; seriesIndex <= 4; seriesIndex++)
{
    TextBox t = ctrl.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "tbVarName" + i);
    if(t != null) dataChart.Series["Variable " + seriesIndex].LegendText = t.Text;

}
```

This will not require an array but you could end with a bigger loop if you have many controls of type textbox and it is not worth the effort if the TextBox are children of different containers (panels, groupboxes)